# Sending AWS EC2 RestAPI using Postman returns error

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postman

I am trying to send a EC2 RestAPI (DescribeInstances) using Postman application. I created a user in IAM in AWS. I generated a AccessKeyId and SecretKey for that particular user, and gave the user "AmazonEC2FullAccess" policy (all EC2 access).
I used the following steps in Postman to send the ResAPI:

- "Get" operation, set End Point to https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances
- In the "Authorization" Tab, selected "AWS Signature" and set the following fields:

  - AccessKey = ACCESSKEYEXAMPLE
  - SecretKey = SECRETKEYEXAMPLE
  - AWS Region = us-west-1
  - Service Name = ec2
- Click on "Update Request", which ends up generating 3 Headers.  I used the info from the generated Headers to modify the endpoint as follows:

https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2016-11-15&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ACCESSKEYEXAMPLE/20170913/us-west-1/ec2/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170913T013055Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type&X-Amz-Signature=amzsignaturesamplegenerated

- "Content-Type" header is set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", and deleted X-Amz-Date and Authorization headers.

When I sent the RestAPI by clicking on "Send", I get the following error response:
Status : "401 Unauthorized"

`AuthFailure`AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials4bc49d04-2115-4b95-8af5-5ac879ac5df3

The error seems to suggest a malformed RestAPI as opposed to an unauthorized access. Tried different variations, very confused. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: `ec2.amazonaws.com` is not the endpoint for us-west-1.  The correct hostname is `ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: Changing just the endpoint did not help, same error message.  However, changing the endpoint as you suggested and putting the auth credentials as a Header parameter got the API to work (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html#sigv4-add-signature-auth-header).   Any idea why putting the auth credential as a query fails?  Thank you again.

Comment: It's difficult to be certain, but your description makes it sound like you tinkered with the request after generating the URL.  For a `GET` request, the browser would not normally set a `Content-Type` header, as it would with a `POST`.

Answer (score 4):

I just found the solution to the same issue. Your URL should be:

https://ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2016-11-15

It didn't work until I added `&Version=2016-11-15` and the region.

[This AWS Documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html#common-parameters-sigv4) says that `Version` is mandatory

Comment: Yes this worked for me in 2020. The version has to be exact, not just any old date.. for me .. https://ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2016-11-15

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement @chriscatfr answer, here is a screenshot how to set postman parameters to query for instances in `us-east-1` region:

[image]